# configure dockerd to log userid or username of the user who is launching the container

Tags: docker, syslog

I updated docker daemon config to enable debug mode for dockerd daemon on Linux. And also using rsyslog I managed to create a separate debug log file. Now I want to log the userid/name of the user launching a container in that log file. I explored docker logging drivers, couldn't find anything relevant there. Is there any way to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The `dockerd` process doesn't know. The user is anyone with access to the API, typically the `docker.sock` socket, but it could also be a remote connection over the network if that's been enabled. There's no user credentials passed in that access. Realize the `docker` client is just a thin client passing json API requests to the `dockerd` API, and the calling user is not part of that request.

It may be possible to configure an [authz plugin](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_authorization/) that depends on [mTLS authentication into the docker API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/), but that's additional configuration that most don't do, and then it may only be possible to add that logging within the plugin itself.

I'd recommend treating the docker engine as a low level tool and implement user credentials and authentication at a higher level. This is similar to how Docker implemented their UCP tool, and also how Kubernetes can run on top of docker.